# Unity, animation playing repeatedly without input

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to make a game in Unity. I am very new to coding, but I have a script for character movement. However, when I press play, the character glitches in and out of the crouch and idle animations rapidly. When I hit the crouch key the character crouches and the glitching stops, but as soon as I let go it resumes. Here is my entire script.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{

    public CharacterController2D controller;
    public Animator animator;

    float horizontalMove = 0f;

    public float runSpeed = 40f;

    bool jump = false;
    bool crouch = false;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        horizontalMove = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * runSpeed;

        animator.SetFloat("Speed", Mathf.Abs (horizontalMove));

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            jump = true;
            animator.SetBool("IsJumping", true);
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = true;
        }
        else if (Input.GetButtonUp("Crouch"))
        {
            crouch = false;
        }
    }
    public void OnLanding()
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsJumping", false);
    }

    public void OnCrouching(bool isCrouching)
    {
        animator.SetBool("IsCrouching", isCrouching);
    }
        void FixedUpdate()
        {
            //Move our character
            controller.Move(horizontalMove * Time.fixedDeltaTime, crouch, jump);
        jump = false;

        }
    }
```

In the Unity animator, the animations are just firing off rapidly. Forgive me if this is an easy fix. Any help would be appreciated.

Edit-
In the animator, the parameter named “IsCrouching” is blinking checked and unchecked whether I hit the key or not.

Comment: other than you never unset jump,  check your animator settings, you can watch them at runtime and see whats set and see what is triggering, and check the state as to why

Answer (score 0):

I see you watched the Brackeys tutorial. You probably have not set correct conditions of the transitions. See again the video from this fragment: [2D Animation in Unity (Tutorial) - 16:52](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hkaysu1Z-N8&feature=youtu.be&t=1012)

Comment: I indeed did watch that tutorial. Pretty informative from a newbie perspective. 
Either way, I’ve gone in and out of these setting over and over, even redone them several times. I assumed at first that was the problem as well but I still can’t find it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Player -> Character Control 2D -> What is Ground and deselect Player.
Otherwise your player ducks below itself.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit on this?

Comment: If the Player colids with itself you get strange bugs like this one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also new and I also had the same problem. Idk if it's solved already but well.. It seems like Brakeys didn't said anything but you need to set your Player to "Player" Layer and then this thing about "what is ground" actually works. But you alse for some reason can't see the character in the Scene view anymore but that's a different problem and I still didn't figured it out haha

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).